# transform doesn't work properly on g element

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, svelte

I am trying d3.js with sveltejs by implementing a simple bar chart, however, the `g` element is not transformed correctly on chrome, although in the devtool the `translate` values are correct. the `g` group element should be transformed `100px` from left, and `20px` from top, but it doesn't relative to the `svg` element. Also, the `width` and `height` of the `g` element are not static, which means `g` grows with the elements inside it, which is not desired action.

Here is the code

```
<script>
  import * as d3 from 'd3';
  let data = [
    { name: 'Apple', amount: 20 },
    { name: 'Orange', amount: 80 },
    { name: 'Banana', amount: 50 },
    { name: 'Grapes', amount: 10 },
  ];

  let width = 600;
  let height = 400;

  let margins = { top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 100, left: 100 };

  let innerWidth = width - margins.left - margins.right;
  let innerHeight = height - margins.top - margins.bottom;

  const xScale = d3
    .scaleBand()
    .domain(data.map((d) => d.name))
    .range([0, innerWidth])
    .paddingInner(0.1)
    .paddingOuter(0.1);
  const yScale = d3
    .scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(data, (d) => d.amount)])
    .range([innerHeight, 0]);
</script>

<div class="canvas">
  <svg {width} {height}>
    <g
      width={innerWidth}
      height={innerHeight}
      transform={`translate(${margins.left}px, ${margins.top}px)`}
    >
      {#each data as d}
        <rect
          width={xScale.bandwidth()}
          height={innerHeight - yScale(d.amount)}
          x={xScale(d.name) + xScale.bandwidth() / 2}
          y={yScale(d.amount)}
        />
      {/each}
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>

<style>
  .canvas {
    margin-top: 100px;
    width: 600px;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: #fff;
  }
</style>
```

and here the images that illustrate the dimensions and transformation of the `svg` and `g` elements

[image]
[image]

**EDIT 1**: when I removed the units from the `translate` function, the `g` element changes its position within the `svg` element, but it's still not the correct position, and now the `g` element goes outside the `svg` element as in the image below

[image]

Comment: remove the units. SVG attribute transforms don't allow them. Units are for CSS transforms.

Comment: @RobertLongson I removed the units, but still the `g` element's position is not right. See my update on the question

Comment: There's also no such thing as width and height for <g> elements. They are always simply the size of their contents. If you need something with a fixed width/height you can use an <svg> element. Alternatively perhaps you just need to translate the <g> element with different values.

Comment: @RobertLongson Thanks. But even so, I set the maximum range value for the `xScale` and `yScale` to be `innerWidth` and `innerHeight`, which means the bar chart should take the whole `innerWidth X innerHeight` space, which should be the size of the g element, right?

Comment: @RobertLongson Also, I have noticed that if I remove the `transform` attribute from `g`, the group element doesn't start at (0,0) of the `svg`. Why? There is some initial shift. I think that's why the `g` element doesn't look right